# Expected argument to be of type `array` but received type `string` - image-webpack-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, node-modules

I'm using `image-webpack-loader` but I got this error message:

I import my images like this:

```
import icon10 from '../../assets/img/icon10.png';
```

---

```
ERROR in ./app/assets/img/icon10.png
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/image-webpack-loader/index.js):
ArgumentError: Expected argument to be of type `array` but received type `string`
    at input (C:\Users\***\Desktop\pos\node_modules\imagemin-pngquant\index.js:32:3)
    at <anonymous>
 @ ./app/containers/Home/index.js 51:0-49 200:13-19
 @ ./app/containers/Home/Loadable.js
 @ ./app/containers/App/index.js
 @ ./app/app.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/react-app-polyfill/ie11.js ./app/app.js
```

Comment: open an issue on their repository

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I guess you should put your `Webpack` configuration for a better explanation. I believe your main issue is on your `Webpack`, based on the document you must set your loader like below:

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
    use: [
      'file-loader',
      {
        loader: 'image-webpack-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader/issues/178), you probably need to change following settings in your `webpack.config.js`:

Instead of

```js
pngquant: {
  quality: '65-90',
  speed: 4,
},
```

you need to use

```js
pngquant: {
  quality: [0.65, 0.90],
  speed: 4,
},
```